# Custom Alert doesn't work in JQuery UI

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

As the title states, I am encountering a weird bug in javascript.
In my php I am echoing out javascript that renders a jquery popup alert box to the screen.

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet"   
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
                <script src="../functions.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript"> JQueryAlert("HELLO!", 120);</script>';
```

functions.js

```
     function JQueryAlert(message,windowHeight){
    if (!windowHeight) var windowHeight = 470;

    $("#msgdialog").remove();

    $("body").append("<div id=\'msgdialog\'></div>"); 

    thatmsg = $("#msgdialog");

    $("#msgdialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 770,
        height: windowHeight,
        context: thatmsg,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel" : function (){
                thatmsg.dialog("close");
            },
            "OK" : function (){
                loadPage("combat.php");
            }
        }
    });     

    $("#msgdialog").html(message);
    $("#msgdialog").dialog(\'open\');
}
```

However, it only displays the pop up alert box *sometimes*. The rest of the time the screen just flashes and doesn't display the pop up box. Any ideas why it is behaving this way? Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/ - a live example will make it easier to identift the problem

Comment: The console should tell you the story.. F12 now..

Comment: Any relevant console output?

Comment: - An html ID (and open) must be between double quote - You forget the var to declare a variable;

Comment: `$("#msgdialog").dialog(\'open\');` looks wrong.

Comment: Do you think it's a javascript bug or is it your own coding :-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "screen flashes"? Btw, `….dialog(\'open\');` looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try placing the call to your function in the document ready eventhandler?

Something like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    JQueryAlert("HELLO!", 120);
  });
</script>
```

My guess is that since you're accessing the DOM in your function, sometimes the DOM isn't completely loaded before your code executes...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug...
you can not manipulate the page elements before they are actually rendered in place.
Instead of JQueryAlert("HELLO!", 120);

use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    JQueryAlert("HELLO!", 120);
}
```

which will display your alert when the document is ready